# $|f(x)| \leq g(x) \forall x$, and $\lim _{x \rightarrow a} g(x)=0$, what is $\lim _{x \rightarrow a} f(x)$? What if $\lim _{x \rightarrow a} g(x)=5$?

Tags: limits

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\text { Suppose }|f(x)| \leq g(x) \text { for all } x . \text { What can you conclude about } \lim _{x \rightarrow a} f(x) \text { if } \lim _{x \rightarrow a} g(x)=0 ?\\
&\text { What if } \lim _{x \rightarrow a} g(x)=5 ?
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Try sketching a graph.

Comment: Hint: remember that $|f(x)|\le g(x)$ is equivalent to $-g(x) \le f(x) \le g(x)$.

Comment: yes I know $ -g(x) \leq f(x) \leq g(x) $. But I don't know why that relates to the limits.

Comment: Re Greg Martin's comment, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem.

Comment: Thank you. I will peruse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$|f(x)| \leq g(x)$ means that $$-g(x) \leq f(x) \leq g(x)$$

If $g(x)\to 0$, then $-g(x)\to 0$ too! Can we use the **Sandwich theorem**?

However, if $g(x)\to 5$, then $-g(x) \to -5$ and not much can be said about $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ in this case.

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Can the sketch be useful in finding limit of $f(x)$?

[image]